# Which Goodness of Fit Test to use when

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, goodness-of-fit

I would like to know which goodness-of-fit test I should use and when. My choices are Anderson-Darling, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Kuiper, Pearson $\chi^2$, and Watson $U^2$, and Cramer von Mises. My data sets are 100 to 1000 data points at a time. The distributions vary and no specific distribution can be assumed to monopolize my data sets. I can't seem to find a good reference when to use which. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for general knowhow/theory? Or do you have a real-life problem?

Comment: I am trying to understand which test would be best to use when for my research. I have been searching for a while now but I cannot seem to find a concrete structure when to use which. From what I gathered so far, the Anderson-Darling seems to be the best to emphasize tails of a distribution which the KS more for the midsection. Its baffling to me that there does not seem to be a good list of conditions of when to use which.